# How to Analyze GCP Cloud Firewall Standard Rules: Data Processing Fee

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've had a very large increase in my data processing fees, but my VM networking has remained consistent. As well I haven't changed or altered my Firewall rules.

I've also confirmed that there's no updates to Cloud Functions either.

Has anyone ever seen this before?

I'm being billed on the `Standard` tier, and wonder if this was somehow switched on.

- How do I turn off the `Standard Rules` and move to `Essentials`
  (scroll down to pricing https://cloud.google.com/firewall?hl=en)
- How do I find which services are contributing to this?

**Billing Increase**
[image: Billing]

**VM Networking from Compute Engine Observability Dashboard**
[image: VM Networking for Month]

**Sent Bytes in Monitoring Dashboard (Similar for Received)**
[image: Sent Bytes for Month - Received is similar]

Answer (score 1):

It is better to reach the [billing support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing) of GCP. They can help you navigate where and what exactly costs you. From there you might be able to find the “why” it has cost you. Use the same method that you use to share here in your question.